# How prove this $\frac{\sin{(A-B)}\sin{(A-C)}}{\sin{2A}}+\frac{\sin{(B-C)}\sin{(B-A)}}{\sin{2B}}+\frac{\sin{(C-A)}\sin{(C-B)}}{\sin{2C}}\ge 0$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

let $0<A,B,C<\dfrac{\pi}{2}$,and $A+B+C=\pi$,prove that

$$\dfrac{\sin{(A-B)}\sin{(A-C)}}{\sin{2A}}+\dfrac{\sin{(B-C)}\sin{(B-A)}}{\sin{2B}}+\dfrac{\sin{(C-A)}\sin{(C-B)}}{\sin{2C}}\ge 0$$

my idea
$$\sin{2B}\sin{2C}\sin{(A-B)}\sin{(A-C)}+\sin{2A}\sin{2C}\sin{(B-C)}\sin{(B-A)}+\sin{2A}\sin{2B}\sin{(C-A)}\sin{(C-B)}\ge 0$$

But following I can't,

and I find sometime,I have find the Similar quetions:http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?p=128597&sid=55397cc8fe6b896712e5495b124dd247#p128597

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sin{2B}\sin{2C}\sin{(A-B)}\sin{(A-C)}=\\\sin(2(\pi-A-C))\sin(2(\pi-A-B))\sin{(A-B)}\sin{(A-C)}\\=4[\sin(A+C)\cos(A+C)][\sin(A-C)\cos(A-C)]\sin(A+B)\sin(A-B)\\ =\cos(B)\cos(C)[\sin^{2}(A)-\sin^{2}(B)][\sin^{2}(A)-\sin^{2}(C)]$$

Using the [extended Schur's Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%27s_inequality)
 $$\sum \cos(B)\cos(C)[\sin^{2}(A)-\sin^{2}(B)][\sin^{2}(A)-\sin^{2}(C)]\geq0$$

Comment: Thank you,But $$\sin{(2(\pi-A-C))}=\sin{2(A+C)}$$

Comment: @math110: I have changed the answer.Is it correct?

Comment: and Now have same wrong, $\cos{(A-C)}$ is $=\cos{(A+B)}=-cos{C}$,and folwing is true.Thank you,It's nice!+1